# add class to a in menu after scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, addclass

How to add class to link in menu after scroll.

script add class after click but no when I scroll.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ggr88uo/42/)

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img src="http://rafal.codeandroll.pl/Project_PSI/images/header.jpg" alt="gra o tron" title="gra o tron" style="width:100%;"/>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul class="menu_top">
            <a href="#home"><li class="m_top active">home</li></a>
            <a href="#about"><li class="m_top">about</li></a>
            <a href="#galery"><li class="m_top">galery</li></a>
            <a href="#xxx"><li class="m_top">xxx</li></a>
            <a href="#contact"><li class="m_top">contact</li></a> 
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id='home'>

    </div>
    <div id='about'>

    </div>
    <div id='galery'>

    </div>
    <div id='xxx'>

    </div>
    <div id='contact'>

    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <span class="copyright">
            Projekt i wykonanie :<a href="#">#</a>
        </span>      
    </div>
</body>
```

my code exist on fiddle but no on my page on localhost i don't know what a js scripts i must implement to my project. Please help me with it.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. What do you want it to do? I can't understand the problem.

Comment: i want to add class activ to element when i scroll page by my mouse .
scroll after click is done.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer the first part of your question here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Psylene/3ggr88uo/45/)

The part that you were looking for to adjust the `active` class state is as follows.
This would be added to the `$(window).scroll` function

```
    var anchors = ["home","about","galery","xxx","contact"];
        $.each(anchors,function(i,v) {
            var anchor_offset = $("#"+v).offset().top; 
            if ( $(window).scrollTop() > anchor_offset )
            {
                $("a li").removeClass("active");
                $('a[href=#'+v+'] > li').addClass("active");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Great! Just one thing ->  if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= anchor_offset ), to avoid problem on link clicking, when scrollTop is adjusted on click.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not loading jQuery on your localhost.
Try adding

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

That will add jQuery to your program. jsFiddle does this automatically.

Comment: i added this code what you send here and all the time script do nothink all the time 0 animations in scrollto